# Does Coldfusion have a "Global" structure

Tags: coldfusion, scope

Does Coldfusion have a "Global" structure where the expressions `global["FORM"]`, `global["URL"]`, `global["APPLICATION"]`, `global["SESSION"]`, etc. are valid?

Comment: May I ask what would be the purpose of this structure in your application? Just curious.

Comment: Specifically I'm looking at validating the existence of a list of required URL/FORM fields.  Generally i'm looking to write a function that takes a single structure and a list and returns true if all items in list exist in the structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

no.  Form, URL, Application, Session etc are all 'global' already.  The underlying Java has got this, if you just want to dump out all the scopes at once:

```
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getBuiltInScopes()#">
```

Or at least that used to work, but in CF9 you have to use this instead:

```
<cfdump var="#getPageContext().getCFScopes()#">
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, but the answer is, "Nope." (am I up to 30 characters yet?)

Answer (score 0):

My take is that you are out of luck with FORM and URL scope.
You can access all user sessions running on a CF instance using SessionTracker Java object:

```
<cfset sessionTrackerObj = createObject("java","coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker")>
<cfoutput><p>There are #sessionTrackerObj.getSessionCount()# active sessions</p></cfoutput>
```

Dump the sessionTrackerObj to view its structure.

The same goes for the APPLICATION scope:

```
<cfset appTrackerObj = createObject(“java”,”coldfusion.runtime.ApplicationScopeTracker”)>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This is not at all what was asked.